# using C++ templates to switch strategies / algorithms

Tags: c++, templates, strategy-pattern

I have a C++ class that might work with linear or binary search.

Currently I have additional member variable that show what search to be used.

I know how I can do the search with Java-like virtual functions (strategy pattern or template method),
but I am curious what is best practice this to be done compile time with templates<>?

Current (simplified) code looks like this:

```
int MyArray::lookup(const String &key) const{
    if (lookupMethod == LINEAR_SEARCH)
        return lookupLinearSearch(key);
    else
        return lookupBinarySearch(key);
}
```

Comment: so you want to specify `lookupMethod` at compile time? depending on what? please clarify

Comment: If you want to choose at compile time, use `template`s.  Otherwise, your code works.  You add a second parameter for the `lookupMethod` and use function overloading.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Your issue to resolve is that templates *use data types, not values*; so you'll have to figure out a way to do the switching based on data types.

Comment: yes, compile time. I will edit the question soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious way is to encapsulate the strategies in types and implement lookup() as a function template:

```
namespace searchStrategy {
    struct linearSearch {
        static auto lookup(const MyArray& a, const String &key)
        -> int {
            return a.lookupLinearSearch(key);
        };
    };

    struct binarySearch {
        static auto lookup(const MyArray& a, const String &key)
        -> int {
            return a.lookupBinarySearch(key);
        };
    };
}

class MyArray {
    public:
        template <typename LookupStrategy>
        auto lookup(const String &key) const
        -> int {
            return LookupStrategy::lookup(*this, key);
        };
};

// ...
auto myArray = MyArray{};
mArray.lookup<searchStrategy::binarySearch>("asdf"s);
```

Alternatively you can specialize the template and use the strategy type as tag only:

```
namespace searchStrategy {
    struct linearSearch {};    
    struct binarySearch {};
}

class MyArray {
    public:
        template <typename LookupStrategy>
        int lookup(const String &key) const;
        template <>
        int lookup<searchStrategy::linearSearch>(const String &key) const {
            return lookupLinearSearch(key);
        };
        template <>
        int lookup<searchStrategy::binarySearch>(const String &key) const {
            return lookupBinarySearch(key)
        };
};


// ...
auto myArray = MyArray{};
mArray.lookup<searchStrategy::binarySearch>("asdf"s);
```

Now you might prefer to not have to define the template parameters, but use a function parameter instead. You don't even need templates for that, but just method overloading:

```
namespace searchStrategy {
    struct LinearSearchT {};    
    struct BinarySearchT {};
    static const LinearSearchT linearSearch;
    static const BinarySearchT binarySearch;
}

class MyArray {
    public:
        int lookup(const String &key,
                   const searchStrategy::linearSearchT strategy) const {
            return lookupLinearSearch(key);
        };
        int lookup(const String &key,
                   const searchStrategy::binarySearchT strategy) const {
            return lookupBinarySearch(key)
        };
};


// ...
auto myArray = MyArray{};
mArray.lookup("asdf"s, searchStrategy::binarySearch);
```

Looks like dynamically choosing the strategy, but is static. You can not do something like this:

```
mArray.lookup("asdf"s, (someReason) ?
                           searchStrategy::binarySearch :
                           searchStrategy::linearSearch);
```

In that case you'd have to write

```
if( someReason )
    mArray.lookup("asdf"s, searchStrategy::binarySearch);
else
    mArray.lookup("asdf"s, searchStrategy::linearSearch);
```

Beware: all code in this answer is untested. It will contain bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template specialization, provided lookupMethod is known at compile time.
For example, you can do it like this:

```
template <int METHOD> 
int MyArray::lookup(const String& key); // Not implemented
template<>
int MyArray::lookup<LINEAR_SEARCH>(const String& key) {
    return lookupLinearSearch(key);
}

template<>
int MyArray::lookup<BINARY_SEARCH>(const String& key) {
    return lookupBinarySearch(key);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to introduce all the boilerplate of having two template specializations, see my answer.

Comment: @NirFriedman, depends on your idea of boilerplate. I find yours more boilerplace, and it also has branching (yes, likely to be thrown out by optimizer - but syntaxically it is there).

Comment: I guess that is technically true in some kind of extreme limit, but this is relatively objective, considering you've written out the signature 3 times, which contains no new information. I think most people find ifs more readable than template specializations, they're much simpler, and there is no run-time cost.

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to always commit to which strategy you are going to use at compile time, you can do this:

```
enum class METHOD {LINEAR_SEARCH, BINARY_SEARCH};

template <METHOD M>
int MyArray::lookup(const String & key) {
    if (M == METHOD::LINEAR_SEARCH)
        return lookupLinearSearch(key);
    else
        return lookupBinarySearch(key);
}
```