# Using C++ templates to switch algorithms

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a C++ class that has a `pointQuery` function. Currently, when I have to switch between linear and binary search, I comment the other part of the code. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263375/using-c-templates-to-switch-strategies-algorithms) post, and tried to refactor my code. My code goes something as:

```
namespace searchStrategy{
    struct linearSearch{};    
    struct binarySearch{};
}

template<typename T, typename LookupStrategy> class leaf:public rtNode<T>{
    public:T points[maxCapLeaf][d]; // search to be done on this array
    // some other class members, most of which used in the search

    template<typename searchStrategy::linearSearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
        // some code
    }

    template<typename searchStrategy::binarySearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
        // some code
    }

};
```

The class' objects are created as:

```
leaf<T, LookupStrategy>* temp = new leaf<T, LookupStrategy>(some_input_params);
```

where `LookupStrategy` is `searchStrategy::binarySearch` or `searchStrategy::linearSearch`.

When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
/file_address/template.cpp:164:39: error: non-type template parameters of class type only available with ‘-std=c++2a’ or ‘-std=gnu++2a’
  164 |     template<typename searchStrategy::linearSearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/file_address/template.cpp:200:39: error: non-type template parameters of class type only available with ‘-std=c++2a’ or ‘-std=gnu++2a’
  200 |     template<typename searchStrategy::binarySearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/file_address/template.cpp:200:58: error: ‘template<class T, class LookupStrategy> template<<typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool leaf<T, LookupStrategy>::pointQuery(const T*) const’ cannot be overloaded with ‘template<class T, class LookupStrategy> template<<typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool leaf<T, LookupStrategy>::pointQuery(const T*) const’
  200 |     template<typename searchStrategy::binarySearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
/file_address/template.cpp:164:58: note: previous declaration ‘template<class T, class LookupStrategy> template<<typeprefixerror><anonymous> > bool leaf<T, LookupStrategy>::pointQuery(const T*) const’
  164 |     template<typename searchStrategy::linearSearch> bool pointQuery(const T* f) const{
      |
```

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this? (Please note that the function needs to remain in the class itself, I can't shift it to the namespace because a lot of class members are used in the search functions) Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(partial) specialization might be a solution, but member/function cannot be partial specialized, you might then partial specialize the whole class.

As alternatives,

In C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
bool pointQuery(const T* f) const
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<LookupStrategy, searchStrategy::linearSearch>)
        // some code
    } else { // searchStrategy::binarySearch
        // some code
    }
}
```

In C++20, `requires`:

```
bool pointQuery(const T* f) const
requires(std::is_same_v<LookupStrategy, searchStrategy::linearSearch>)
{
    // some code
}

bool pointQuery(const T* f) const
requires(std::is_same_v<LookupStrategy, searchStrategy::binarySearch>)
{
    // some code
}
```

In previous standard, you might use tag dispatching:

```
private:
bool pointQuery(searchStrategy::linearSearch, const T* f) const
{
    // some code
}

bool pointQuery(searchStrategy::binarySearch, const T* f) const
{
    // some code
}
public:
bool pointQuery(const T* f) const
{
    return pointQuery(LookupStrategy{}, f);
}
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to use if-else thinking that they might give slower performance. Is it correct or it doesn't affect performance at all?

Comment: `if constexpr` is done at compile time, so no runtime overhead. (For regular `if`, compilers might optimize easily that but indeed, no guaranties).

Comment: So the C++17 solution only increases complie time, and *NOT* runtime at all?

Comment: For runtime, no overheads (only the right block is present). For compile time, not sure which alternatives would be the most or less costly. I would say equivalent.

Comment: Compile time isn't an issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace searchStrategy {
    struct linearSearch{};    
    struct binarySearch{};
}

template<typename T, typename LookupStrategy> class leaf: public rtNode<T> {
  private:
    // Overload 1
    bool pointQuery(const T* f, linearSearch) const {
        // some code
    }

    // Overload 2
    bool pointQuery(const T* f, binarySearch) const {
        // some code
    }

  public:
    T points[maxCapLeaf][d];

    bool pointQuery(const T* f) const {
        return pointQuery(points, LookupStrategy{});
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did exactly as you said, and have editted my post. Can you please take a look?